# How to assign default values to a Webform Structured Textfield?

Tags: 7, webforms

Using [`hook_webform_component_render_alter()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_component_render_alter/7) I am setting the default values for some components on a webform if a user has the corresponding fields in his/her profile filled out.

```
if($component['cid'] == 24){
    $element['#default_value'] = $myValue; 
}
```

This works for every type of webform component thus far until I used a [Webform Structured Textfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_structured_text).

When I add the same code to the Webform Structured Textfield It only takes one digit from the number i'm assigning it. My input mask for the field is: **9999999** allowing the user to only enter 7 digits.

For simplicity sake, I have a variable: `$myValue = 1234567;`

When I assign the `$myValue` variable to the webform component the textfield will only show the value **1** instead of the **1234567**. When I assign the variable to other webform components the value 1234567 is shown.

**Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong when assigning default values to a Webform Structured Textfield?** And if anyone knows any other ways to modify this field programmatically that would be sufficient as well.